# What sort of robot would one use to tie precise knots in a string?

Tags: mechanism, research

I need many knots tied repetitively and consistently in a string. I have been trying to make something which ties knots for me in a consistent manner. I've got a project which requires a few hundred strings, each with knots tied at regular intervals. I'm designing my own mechanism, but if another mechanism of the same sort already exists, I can draw a lot of inspiration from it.

The most important parameters are:.
The knots must not vary in size/line use by more than a millimeter.
The knots must be square knots, or they can be simply looped to melt the line back on itself.

What kind of robots or mechanisms currently exist that can tie knots according to the parameters above? Do any such mechanisms exist?

Here are some examples of what I'm looking for the mechanism to do.
[image]
[image]

Comment: @jsotola added pictures.

Comment: the pictures make your post unclear .... those are not knots per se .... which part does your machine do? ... the sewing part or the loop through the carbiner part?

Comment: @jsotola the sewing, I just need the lines. nothing else

Comment: I think that a machine for making loops on rope does exist ... not sure how it works ... have some ideas how it might work